# Найти факториал длинного числа

Tags: c++

Программа ищет факториал длинного числа, и она как бы уже готова, но при любом запуске выдает исключение вида 0x111CDDB. Подскажите, где может быть ошибка?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void Input(char *N) 
{
    int i = 0;
    N[i] = getchar();
    while (N[i] != '\n')
    {
        N[i] -= 48;
        i++;
        N[i] = getchar();
    };

    printf("\n");
}

bool IsEqual(char a[], int na, char b[], int nb)
{
    int i;
    if (na != nb)return false;
    else
        for (i = 0; i < na; i++)
            if (a[i] != b[i])return false;
    return true;
}


void Umn(char *a, int &n, char *b, int &m)
{
    char c[1000];
    int i, j, l, o;

    //Обнуляем резултат
    for (i = 0; i<n + m; i++)
        c[i] = 0;
    //Умножение
    for (i = 0; i<m; i++) {
        o = 0; l = 0;
        for (j = n - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            c[j + m - i] += (a[j] * b[m - 1 - i] + o) % 10;
            if (c[j + m - i]>9) {
                l = c[j + m - i] / 10;
                c[j + m - i] = c[j + m - i] % 10;
            }
            o = (a[j] * b[m - i - 1] + o) / 10 + l;
            if (j == 0) c[j + m - 1 - i] += o;
            l = 0;
        }
    }
    //Избавляемся от ведущих нулей
    n = n + m;
    while (c[0] == 0) {
        for (j = 0; j<n - 1; j++)
            c[j] = c[j + 1];
        if (n != 1) n--; else break;
    }
    //Вывод результата
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
        a[i] = c[i];

}

void Plus(char *i, int &lengI, int n)
{
    char c[1000];
    int pos = 0;
    for (int y = lengI - 1; y >= 0; i--)
    {
        c[pos] = i[y];
        pos++;
    }

    pos = 0;
    c[0] += n;
    bool change = false;
    while (c[pos] >= 10)
    {
        bool change = true;
        c[pos + 1]++;
        c[pos++] -= 10;
    }
    if (change) lengI++;

    pos = 0;
    for (int z = lengI - 1; z >= 0; z--)
    {
        i[pos] = c[z];
        pos++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char N[100];
    Input(N);

    char i[100];
    i[0] = 2;
    int lengI = 1;

    char Result[1000];
    Result[0] = 1;
    int leng = 1;

    while (!(IsEqual(i, lengI, N, leng)))
    {
        Umn(Result, leng, i, lengI);
        Plus(i, lengI, 1);
    }

    for (int z = 0; z < leng; z++)
    {
        cout << Result[z];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void Plus(char *i, int &lengI, int n)


    for (int y = lengI - 1; y >= 0; i--)
    {
        c[pos] = i[y];
        pos++;
    }
```

Декрементируется `i`, а должно `y`.