# Посчитать факториал числа большее 10 но меньшего 100

Tags: c++

Ищу факториал числа большего 10. Использую длинные числа, но когда дело доходит до прибавления 1 к числу, `(2! = 1 * (1+1))`, то функция робит не верно. Вопрос, что я сделал не так? `i` - искомое число, `lengI` - количество цифр в числе, `n = 1`.

```
void Plus(char *i, int &lengI, int n)
{
    char c[1000];
    int pos = 0;
    for (int y = lengI - 1; y >= 0; y--)
    {
        c[pos] = i[y];
        pos++;
    }

    pos = 0;
    c[0] += n;
    bool change = false;
    while (c[pos] >= 10)
    {
        bool change = true;
        c[pos + 1]++;
        c[pos++] -= 10;
    }
    if (change) lengI++;

    pos = 0;
    for (int z = lengI - 1; z >= 0; z--)
    {
        i[pos] = c[z];
        pos++;
    }
}
```

Comment: "то функция робит не верно" - почему бы Вам не объяснить, в чем это "не верно" заключается, и чем оно отлочается от "верно"?

Answer (score 1):

В самом начале залить **ВЕСЬ** массив `с` нулями и вот это

```
bool change = false;
while (c[pos] >= 10)
{
    bool change = true;
    c[pos + 1]++;
    c[pos++] -= 10;
}
if (change) lengI++;
```

Переписать так

```
while (c[pos] >= 10)
{
    int delta = c[pos] / 10;
    c[pos++] &= 10;
    c[pos] += delta;
}
if (pos >= lengI)
  lengI = pos;
```

Вопрос о необходимости массива `с` и о том, хватит ли Вам 1000 элементов оставляем открытым

Comment: Массив `char`, так что нужно не забывать про приведение к целому `c[pos] - '0'`.

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, тогда вылетает за пределы массива

Comment: @Anton Shchrov, вот здесь весь код, может глянете , пжлст    http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599190/Найти-факториал-длинного-числа/599196#599196

Comment: @RomaMikov Если Вы выполнили это `В самом начале залить ВЕСЬ массив с нулями`, Вы помещаетесь в 1000 знаков и исходный массив `i` способен вместить в себя новое число, то проблем быть не должно. Разве что объявите его как `int c[1000]`

Answer (score 0):

Вот и готовая прога, которая решает задачу, всем спасибо

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool IsEqual(string N, int colN, int i)
{
    int N1 = atoi((N.c_str()));
    return !(N1 + 1 == i);
}

void Umn(char *a, int &n, char *b, int m)
{
    char c[1000];
    int i, j, l, o;

    //Обнуляем резултат
    for (i = 0; i<n + m; i++)
        c[i] = 0;
    //Умножение
    for (i = 0; i<m; i++) {
        o = 0; l = 0;
        for (j = n - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            c[j + m - i] += (a[j] * b[m - 1 - i] + o) % 10;
            if (c[j + m - i]>9) {
                l = c[j + m - i] / 10;
                c[j + m - i] = c[j + m - i] % 10;
            }
            o = (a[j] * b[m - i - 1] + o) / 10 + l;
            if (j == 0) c[j + m - 1 - i] += o;
            l = 0;
        }
    }
    //Избавляемся от ведущих нулей
    n = n + m;
    while (c[0] == 0) {
        for (j = 0; j<n - 1; j++)
            c[j] = c[j + 1];
        if (n != 1) n--; else break;
    }
    //Вывод результата
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
        a[i] = c[i];

}

int main()
{
    string N; 
    cin >> N; 

    char result[1000];
    result[0] = 1;
    int lengRes = 1;

    for (int i = 2; IsEqual(N, N.size(), i); i++)
    {
        char newI[10];
        string str = to_string(i);
        for (int p = 0; p < 10; p++)newI[p] = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)newI[i] = str[i] - '0';
        Umn(result, lengRes, newI, str.size());
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < lengRes; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", result[i]);
    }

    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```